# How to generate js and html into the same folder using nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, build, nuxt.js, ssg

Commonly, the generated result would looks like this:

```
/dist
-- /_nuxt
---- /static
------ ...(JS files)

-- /page1
---- index.html
-- /page2
---- index.html
```

Depending on my task, I want to design a config.js for people who doesn't familiar with coding, so I want to use nuxtjs generate ssg build files like this dir structure:

```
/dist
-- /page1
---- index.html
---- config.js

-- /page2
---- index.html
---- config.js
```

or likes this:

```
/dist
-- /page1
---- index.html (js in the html)

-- /page2
---- index.html (js in the html)
```

Is this possible to do this?

Comment: That's not an easy task! To be honest I'm not even sure you can customize the nuxt build that much. You wanna take a look at building a [nuxt module](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-build#extend), tweaking the webpack configuration I guess. My advise would be to contact the nuxt team directly on the [nuxtjs discord](https://discord.com/invite/ps2h6QT).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I agree with you, I would ask nuxt team, thanks!